# TEXShop_for Windows 10

Tags: installing

I want to use TEXshop in Windows10, could anyone help me providing a link so that I can install the program successfully?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. What would be good editor of Latex for Windows 10

Comment: If you like TeXShop, try TeXworks.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but TeXShop is a Mac application only. There are many other choices available, both Windows only and cross-platform.  For a big list see:

- [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/2693)

Comment: TeXworks is a cross platform Front End that is based on TeXShop's design values.